# attribute is not retrievable after being set by the ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

After I make the ajax call and get a result. I want to set the attribute to be retrievable by the next jquery console.log method. Unfortunately this does not work.

```
   var other_month = $('#prev-month').attr('data-cur-month', "" + other_month);
    $.post('../wp-content/custom/events/index.php', {
        month: month,
        year: year
    },
    function(data){
        // refactor this so we can do this on the right side.
        $('.event-wrapper-left').html($('.event-wrapper').html());
        $('.event-wrapper').html($('.event-wrapper-right').html());
        $('.event-wrapper-right').html(data);   

        $(self).html( monthNames[d.getMonth()]+ " " + d.getFullYear() + '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>');
        $(self).attr('data-cur-month', "" + new_month);
        $(self).attr('data-cur-year', "" + year);

        $('#prev-month').html( '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>' + monthNames[other_date.getMonth()]+ " " + other_date.getFullYear());
        console.log(other_month);
        $('#prev-month').attr('data-cur-month', other_month);

        // this come out as zero
        console.log($('#prev-month').attr('data-cur-month'));
        $('#prev-month').attr('data-cur-year', other_year);
```

HTML:

```
<a class="pull-left month-left month-changer" href="#" data-cur-year="<?= date('Y', strtotime('-1 month')) ?>" data-cur-month="<?= date('m', strtotime('-1 month')) ?>" id="prev-month"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span><?= date('F Y', strtotime('-1 month')) ?></a>
                    <a class="pull-right month-right month-changer" href="#" data-cur-year="<?= date('Y', strtotime('+3 month')) ?>" data-cur-month="<?= date('m', strtotime('+3 month')) ?>" id="next-month"><?= date('F Y', strtotime('+3 month')) ?><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
```

Comment: what is the output of `console.log(other_month);`

Comment: `other_month` is not even defined in your example. Please create a **complete** example.

Comment: The output is 7 Ill update the question to include the html

Comment: where are you defining other_month and where are you setting it?

Comment: Have you tried using `.data()` instead of `.attr()` ? Something like `$('#prev-month').data('cur-month');`

Comment: You need to show us where you are defining `other_month`. If you don't set it after defining it, it will remain the same.

Comment: editied the question to include the other month init.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like using ajax and populating an attribute is not the best approach. If the attribute is generated using ajax the dom wont recognize it being there and wont know how to access it.

What I have done is refactor my solution to use a variable outside of the ajax function and increment the variable from there instead of storing the variable inside of the element on the page.